# Not enter while loop after mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql

please take a look at this code :

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM shop";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo $result;
    echo "before lop";

    while ($xxx = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "inside lop";
    echo $xxx['column_name'];

 }
    echo "after lop";
```

When I run such code i receive :

```
Resource id #244 
before lop
after lop
```

It did not enter while lop, and I really don't know why :(
I used before such code and there were no problems.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure `$xxx['column_name'];` is a valid column name from the sql you provided?

Comment: @ConradLotz even it is not it should not be the problem the code must have printed the echo "inside top" before the execution and should have given a mysql error for column not found

Answer (score 4):

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM shop";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

 echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Check how many records are present in your `shop` table. I think shop table is empty.That is why not entering in the while loop.

You can do like this

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count > 0) {
   while ($xxx = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo $xxx['column_name'];
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes you rigt, the table is empty, but how can i check it? i just wanted to use wile lop like this :
while ($xxx = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    if($xxx['column_name'] == '') {
return false 
} else {
return true}

 }

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the call to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` has returned false, possibly due to no results being returned from the database, this would cause the while loop to not execute even once. I would check the output of `var_dump(mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` to ensure that data has been returned.

Comment: this is not an answer.you may have posted a comment instead.

Comment: hello

it prints :

resource(244) of type (mysql result)

I also add that I know that when I put this query into phpmyadmin it returns empty result, but i wanted just to check in while lop if result is empty or not. If result is not empty the while lop works it enter it.

Comment: ok but it is not right thing to do,posting your comment as an answer when you have not enough reputation ..

Comment: I apologise, I'm new to this site.